# code tracking and PrestaShop

Tags: javascript, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am very new to Prestashop. I am trying to install a tracking code for an affiliate program that allows me to retrieve info from the order-confirmation page (that's where the code will be embedded) . this is the affiliate tracking code, do you know with what parameters i should replace the parameters inside the ' '. What are the variables for this in prestashop? Thanks very much for your kind answers

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
/*** Do not change ***/
var AWIN = {};
AWIN.Tracking = {};
AWIN.Tracking.Sale = {};

/*** Set your transaction parameters ***/
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.amount = 'SALE_AMOUNT';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.currency = 'GBP';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.orderRef = 'ORDER_REF';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.parts = 'COMMISSION_GROUP:SALE_AMOUNT';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.voucher = 'VOUCHER_CODE';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.test = '1';
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

substitutions are these , they could change based on the theme override

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
/*** Do not change ***/
var AWIN = {};
AWIN.Tracking = {};
AWIN.Tracking.Sale = {};

/*** Set your transaction parameters ***/
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.amount = '{/literal}{$order.revenue}{literal}';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.currency = '{/literal}{$currency.iso_code}{literal}';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.orderRef = '{/literal}{$reference_order}{literal}';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.parts = 'COMMISSION_GROUP:SALE_AMOUNT';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.voucher = 'VOUCHER_CODE';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.test = '1';
//]]>
</script>
{/literal}
```

lacking these two values: "COMMISSION_GROUP:SALE_AMOUNT" and "VOUCHER_CODE" ​​but should depend on the tracking system